# Jenkins how to change the Update Center

Tags: jenkins

I want to create custom Update Center for internal org plugins.

I try to do it with [juseppe](https://hub.docker.com/r/lanwen/juseppe/).

From my Jenkins server I succeed to download the JSON page via `curl` command.

But when I change the default update site to the new URL I still see the official Jenkins plugins and not my.

I didn't see any log of Update Center when I press the <kbd>Check now</kbd> button.

Also I try to use the [UpdateSites Manager plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/UpdateSites+Manager+plugin), but the same problem.

Please advise how I need to configure and where I can find the log of update site.

Answer (score 7):

I activated my custom update center by directly putting it into `$JENKINS_HOME/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sites>
  <site>
    <id>jenkinsupdatecenter</id>
    <url>https://myupdatecenter.local/update-center.json</url>
  </site>
</sites>
```

Comment: my file also updated
<sites>

  <site>
    <id>default</id>
    <url>http://10.235.75.231/update-center.json</url>
  </site>
  <jp.ikedam.jenkins.plugins.updatesitesmanager.ManagedUpdateSite plugin="update-sites-manager@2.0.0">
    <id>internal_plugins</id>
    <url>http://10.235.75.231/update-center.json</url>
    <caCertificate>-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDZTCCA.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----</caCertificate>
    <disabled>false</disabled>
    <note></note>
  </jp.ikedam.jenkins.plugins.updatesitesmanager.ManagedUpdateSite>
</sites>

Comment: I don't use the UpdateSites Manager plugin at all. Can you uninstall that, and then manually change the `hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml` file to the standard form that's shown above?

Answer (score 7):

I set update center in GUI of Jenkins.

In configuration it's illogically hidden in "Plugin Manager" configuration.

JenkinsUrl -> "Manage Jenkins" -> "Manage Plugins" -> "Advanced" -> "Update Site" -> "URL"